# python reverse solve a formatted string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to do opposite of format function to get a dictionary of key value pair,
what I have is a path template with keys defined and I have final path

```
path_template = "/server/{project}/{task}/myfile.{extension}"

mypath_a = "/server/test_project/my_task/myfile.txt"
mypath_b = "/server/test_project/my_task_j/myfile.json"
```

I want to be able to parse the path and build a dictionary like below, anyone has any suggestion
on the best way to approach this or python string formaing may already have some functionality
to parse this

```
parse_path(mypath_a)

{"project":"test_project", "task":"my_task", "extension":"txt"}
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Seems like this would be a very good use of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

She string.split function creates a string array by splitting the string at the designated character. You can use that and look for the '/' and '.' characters.

```
def parse_path(path_string):
    split_array = path_string.split('/',4)
    key = split_array[2]
    task = split_array[3]
    extension = path_string.split('.')[1]
    return {"project": key, "task": task, "extension":extension}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```py
import re

def parse_path(path):
    pattern = '/server/(.+?)/(.+?)/myfile.(.+?)$'
    search = re.search(pattern, path)
    if search:
        return {
            'project': search.group(1),
            'task': search.group(2),
            'extension': search.group(3),
        }
    
print(parse_path('/server/test_project/my_task/myfile.txt'))
# {'project': 'test_project', 'task': 'my_task', 'extension': 'txt'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [lucidity](https://lucidity.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tutorial.html)

```
import lucidty
template = lucidity('ProjectFileStructure', "/server/{project}/{task}/myfile.{extension}")

mypath_a = "/server/test_project/my_task/myfile.txt"
mypath_b = "/server/test_project/my_task_j/myfile.json"
data1 = template.parse(mypath_a)
data2 = template.parse(mypath_b)
print(data1)
print(data2)

# Output 
#  {"project":"test_project", "task":"my_task", "extension":"txt"}
#  {"project":"test_project", "task":"my_task_j", "extension":"json"}
```